# Can leaving car parked long term with flat tyre cause problems?

Tags: tires

car is currently out if user and had been parked up for months.  Not starting either so can’t take it to station for air.

I think I heard leaving it like this can cages either the tyre or wheel to rot? What does this mean and can any part get damaged if you continue to leave parked on a flat tyre?

Thanks.

Comment: But you can bring air to the car, by using an electric or foot pump. I seem to remember a foot pump needing about five pumps per pound pressure, so it's a lot of work!

Comment: A flat tyre is being squeezed and bent in ways for which the tyre was not designed. Because of this, eventually, the structure of the tyre will fail. I have no way to know how long that might take. For myself, I'd feel OK about using an otherwise-sound tyre that had sat flat for a week or two, but months would make me feel nervous. YMMV.

Comment: Jack up, put on a stand or bricks and take it for repair.

Answer (score 2):

It’s bad for the tyre but won’t cause any other problems.  Essentially the sidewall will be bent over and have all the weight on one spot, which is likely to cause delamination.  Either pump the tyre up enough to get it more or less back in shape or change/remove the wheel.

Comment: It is also bad for good tires..

Comment: @Martin it would improve the quality of your comment if you would briefly explain how so.